# Save Exact Scroll Position of UITableview With Dynamic Cell Heights

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to be able to save the last scroll position of a large tableview (8000+ cells). On relaunch I will restore the tableview to exactly that position.

Since many will ask why, it is a book. As such the exact position where user left off is the best user experience. Not the closest cell.

**What does not work:**

`tableView.contentOffset.y` changes maybe due to dynamic cell height

`tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows[0]` is not exact position

Any creative ways to save and restore the exact position?

Comment: it can be achieve using `Restoration Id`. Apple provide this functionality default. You can check with inbuilt `Notes` and `Calendar` App.

Comment: @PratikSodha that sounds like the best solution. I set the two delegate methods in AppDelegate and set restoration ids on my tab bar, nav, view controller, and tableview. Isn't working so far.